# "Promise{<pending>}" in console instead of a value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, promise

I am trying to import a function that fetches data from an api in a file (.src/api/index.js) to my App.js (.src/App.js).

> *.src/api/index.js*

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api';

export const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(url);
        return res;
    } catch (error) {}
};
```

> *.src/App.js*

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchData } from './api';

const App = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const data = fetchData();
        console.log(data);
    }, []);

    return <div></div>;
};

export default App;
};
```

I am getting a `Promise{<pending>}` in my console when I run this but I am trying to get the values in the object.

Answer (score 1):

`fetchData()` is an async function, and you need to `await` it like so:

```
const data = await fetchData();
```

Then, the `useEffect` must also be an async function:

```
useEffect(async () => {
        const data = await fetchData();
        console.log(data);
    }, []);
```

Comment: Except there's no `async` where you use that await

Comment: @PatrickRoberts oh right, sorry. *Something* has to be `async, the function surrounding the call.

Comment: React advice's me not to use the 'async' after useEffect(**async** () => {

Comment: You can also wrap the await inside an immediately-invoked-function-expression like so: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-use-async-function-in-react-hook-useeffect-typescript-js-6204a788a435 @Oluwajolasun

Answer (score 1):

You are not waiting for promise to resolve. use await or .then. If you wanna use await, make callback function of useEffect async function.

```
const App = () => {
    useEffect(async () => {
        const data = await fetchData();
        console.log(data);
    }, []);

    return <div></div>;
};
```

Other approach is to use .then.

```
const App = () => {
    useEffect(async () => {
        const data = fetchData().then((data) => console.log(data));
    }, []);

    return <div></div>;
};
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted... this was the first answer to point out that the `useEffect()` callback needed to be async, which at the time of writing wasn't redundant information.

Comment: React advice's me not to use the 'async' after useEffect(**async** () => {

Comment: I have added second approach. For which react won't give you any warning.